# PHP Recursion: Flatten Tree, Preserve Metadata

Tags: php, recursion, tree, adjacency-list

Imagine you have a tree representing a family that you want to persist to tables, but preserve nesting levels. I'd like to get the post data below into the structure underneath.

I believe a RecursiveIterator might be the way to do this, but I am not sure how I would do so. I have code that works for most cases, but it has become an ugly, bloated thing. I can post that if you'd like.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => Smith
    [type] => Family
    [children] => Array(
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Michael
                    [type] => Uncle
                    [children] => Array(
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Jared
                                    [type] => cousin
                                )
                        )
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Jeff
                    [type] => Dad
                    [children] => Array(
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Jonas
                                    [type] => self
                                )
                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Leah
                                    [type] => sister
                                    [children] => Array(
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Jacob
                                                    [type] => nephew
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

The records for persistence should look like this:

```
Array
(
    stdClass Object ( [name] => Smith [type] => Family [subgroup] => 0 [parent_subgroup] => )
    stdClass Object ( [name] => Michael [type] => Uncle [subgroup] => 1 [parent_subgroup] => 0 )
    stdClass Object ( [name] => Jared [type] => Cousin [subgroup] => 2 [parent_subgroup] => 1 )
    stdClass Object ( [name] => Jeff [type] => Dad [subgroup] => 1 [parent_subgroup] => 0 )
    stdClass Object ( [name] => Jonas [type] => self [subgroup] => 3 [parent_subgroup] => 1 )
    stdClass Object ( [name] => Leah [type] => sister [subgroup] => 3 [parent_subgroup] => 1 )
    stdClass Object ( [name] => Jacob [type] => nephew [subgroup] => 4 [parent_subgroup] => 3 )     
)
```

P.S. No, me and my sister didn't have a kid. That was just my analogy falling on its face. ;)

Comment: I've used `RecursiveIterator` in my code, and my class has also become big and bulky.  It could work here, just try to keep it simple.

Comment: How *exactly* is this object/array laid out?  Where are the child records located?  Your object has `name` and `type` properties, but what property are the child objects in?

Comment: This thread has the exact post data. [link](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/32901351/php-building-an-adjacency-list-through-recursive-iteration)

Comment: In that question, `rules` is an array.  Here, `type` is a string and then the array is just kinda pasted there without a key.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I just wanted to keep it as simple as possible. Eek. Sorry I ripped that introductory paragraph out. This was just meant to be an analogy that had the simplest representation possible.

Comment: Oh!  Ok, that makes sense.  I was trying to hack up an example, but the array/object shown here seemed to be missing a few keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RecursiveIterator` classes can get a bit messy, I like to try to keep them simple.  You can use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to loop over the values of your iterator, it can even give you the current depth (or `subgroup` in your case).

The challenge here is that the parent isn't an array, but we can take care of that in the constructor.

```
<?php
class FamilyIterator implements RecursiveIterator{
    private $data, $counter;

    public function __construct($familyTree){
        $this->data = is_array($familyTree) ? $familyTree : [$familyTree];
    }

    public function current(){
        $row = $this->data[$this->counter];
        return (object)[
            'name' => $row->name,
            'type' => $row->type
        ];
    }

    public function key(){
        return $this->counter;
    }

    public function next(){
        $this->counter++;
    }

    public function rewind(){
        $this->counter = 0;
    }

    public function valid(){
        return $this->counter < count($this->data);
    }

    public function hasChildren(){
        $row = $this->data[$this->counter];
        return isset($row->children);
    }

    public function getChildren(){
        $row = $this->data[$this->counter];
        return new self($row->children);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this class like:

```
$loop = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new FamilyIterator($dataObj),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
```

When you `foreach` over `$loop`, it'll automatically call the `getChildren` method when it needs, so in the `foreach` you'll have each row.  You can even ask `RecursiveIteratorIterator` for the depth.

```
$newData = [];
foreach($loop as $row){
    $row->subgroup = $loop->getDepth();
    $newData[] = $row;
}
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/444078

This may not be *exactly* what you wanted, but hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.  `RecursiveIterator`s don't need to be complicated.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will post the full solution when I have it - it may require a second loop to do the cleanup on the subgroup, but I should be able to derive the parent_subgroup from this.

Comment: @JonasJSchreiber: You can derive that in the loop, or you can even do something like: `__construct($familyTree, $subGroup=0)` (make sure to save `$subGroup` in a class variable), then in `getChildren`, you can increment that: `return new self($row->children, $this->subGroup+1);`.

Comment: Thanks Rocket. I posted your solution on the other thread, since the code I ended up testing and debugging on used the more complex structure. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901351)